# Laravel Paginate with WhereIn clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination, laravel-9

I am trying to get data from the database with paginate in laravel 9. My controller function looks like this:

```
public function get_all_locations(Request $request){
    $locations = Locations::latest()->whereIn('company_id', [$request->company_id])->paginate(1);
    return response()->json([
        'locations' => $locations
    ],200);
}
```

The above code doesn't return anything however it works fine without pagination when I use the code below:

```
public function get_all_locations(Request $request){
    $locations = Locations::whereIn('company_id', [$request->company_id])->get();
    return response()->json([
        'locations' => $locations
    ],200);
}
```

Can you please guide me on what is missing from my function with the paginate?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `$request->company_id`? Is it a single id? or an array of ids? You're wrapping it in an array, like `[$request->company_id]`. That should either be `->where('company_id', $request->company_id)`, or `->whereIn('company_id', $request->input('company_ids')` (notice `company_ids` vs `company_id`; your variable is named all kinds of odd, and there shouldn't be a case for wrapping it in an array)

Comment: @TimLewis, I am fetching a list of locations each has a single id, I changed my code to `->where('company_id', $request->company_id) ` but it still doesn't work when I am using paginate.

Comment: You still didn't really answer what `$request->company_id` is... Can you please do a `dd($request->company_id)` and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74033916/edit) to include that? Also, include what is being returned, i.e. `console.log(response.locations)` (or whatever). It should be returning _something_, even an empty array/object, which would point at an issue with your query.

Comment: Also, an alternative if you're looking for Locations for a single Company, would be `return response()->json(['locations' => Company::findOrFail($request->company_id)->locations()->paginate(1)], 200)`, assuming you have a `Company` model with a `locations` relationship.

Comment: @TimLewis, company_id is a single_id in my database which each location has. here is what we get when I do a console.log of object `[
    {
        "id": 52,
        "title": "New CHalli",
        "longlat": "24.8514006, 67.0099707",
        "address": "New Chali, Karachi, Pakistan",
        "category": null,
        "website": "suleman.shahjahan@gmail.com",
        "email": "suleman.shahjahan@gmail.com",
        "phone": "03232148310",
        "marker_icon": "1665431500.png",
        "photo": "1665436927.jpeg",
        "category_id": 1,
        "company_id": 5
    }
]`

Comment: So yeah, `->whereIn('company_id', [$request->company_id])` is nonsensical; you're wrapping a single `id` in an array so you can use it with `->whereIn()`  `->where('company_id', $request->company_id)` works. And you're getting a single row with `company_id: 5`; make sure you're not passing `page=2` (or similar), since there's only 1 page of results.

Comment: @TimLewis, I am not trying to get a single location however for testing the pagination I have set it to `->paginate(1)` which can be like `paginate(10)`. 

I don't have a company as a model. that is just a random number I have assigned to each location when feeding the data to database.

Comment: No problem; that's a valid scenario, but right now, you _are_ trying to get all Locations for `company_id: 5`, which _is_ a single association (really _should_ have a `Company` model if there's an ID for it, but that's beside the point).

Comment: [link](https://mynearby-locations.herokuapp.com/) so I am trying create an API based application that when someone embed on thier website using a code which has the company_id it will only display locations where `compnay_Id = number` I am not a expert in that however the company id is being generated from the user model it picks logged-in user's id and passes it as company_id when adding location.

Comment: That's not very secure... If the URL is something like `myapp.com/locations?company_id=5`, I can simply change that to `company_id=6` and get someone else's Locations. But none of that is really relevant to your question; as long as `company_id` is a single number, then `return response()->json(['locations' => Location::where('company_id', $request->company_id)->paginate(1)], 200)` should work; does that work, or are you still having issues? You may need to further [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74033916/edit) with more info; we're going in circles 

Comment: @TimLewis, that does work! so I do have an API Key associated with each user and location. I am planning to fetch data when the API key and company_id both match. someone can guess the company_id but they won't be able to guess an API key. Will that make it secure? THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: That's perfect  Some kind of authentication/authorization system to make sure the person making the request to your API is actually allowed to is great! You could lock it down further, by validating that `$request->company_id` is valid for the user/record associated, but at that point it may be overkill. And no problem! Happy to assist!